# Addition of polynomials in Java using LinkedLists

Tags: java, polynomials

I am trying to develop a program that adds two Polynomials using the LinkedList data structure in Java.
As of now, I have the Node class

```
public class Node {
    
    /**
     * Term instance. 
     */
    Term term;
    
    /**
     * Next node in linked list. 
     */
    Node next;
    
    /**
     * Initializes this node with a term with given coefficient and degree,
     * pointing to the given next node.
     * 
     * @param coeff Coefficient of term
     * @param degree Degree of term
     * @param next Next node
     */
    public Node(float coeff, int degree, Node next) {
        term = new Term(coeff, degree);
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

This class just establishes the class for the Nodes of the LinkedList. I also have established all of the related classes.

The issue I am facing is that my addition code(*outlined below*) is returning me the two polynomials added together excluding the final term(*see below*).

**Addition Code**

```
    public static Node add(Node poly1, Node poly2) {
        poly1 = reverse(poly1);
        poly2 = reverse(poly2);
        Node new_Node = new Node(0,0,null);
        Node head = new_Node;
        while(poly1.next != null && poly2.next != null){

            //If power of 1st polynomial is greater then 2nd, then store 1st as it is and move its pointer
            if(poly1.term.degree > poly2.term.degree){
                new_Node.term.degree = poly1.term.degree;
                new_Node.term.coeff = poly1.term.coeff;
                poly1 = poly1.next;
            }
            // If power of 2nd polynomial is greater than the 1st, then store the 2nd as it is and move its pointer
            else if(poly1.term.degree < poly2.term.degree){
                new_Node.term.degree = poly2.term.degree;
                new_Node.term.coeff = poly2.term.coeff;
                poly2 = poly2.next;
            } 
            // If power of both polynomials are the same, then add their coefficients
            else {
                new_Node.term.degree = poly1.term.degree;
                new_Node.term.coeff = poly1.term.coeff + poly2.term.coeff;
                poly1 = poly1.next;
                poly2 = poly2.next;
            }
            // Creates new node
            new_Node.next = new Node(0,0,null);
            new_Node = new_Node.next;

        }
        while(poly1.next != null || poly2.next != null) {
            if(poly1.next != null){
                new_Node.term.degree = poly1.term.degree;
                new_Node.term.coeff = poly1.term.coeff;
                poly1 = poly1.next;
            }
            if(poly2.next != null){
                new_Node.term.degree = poly2.term.degree;
                new_Node.term.coeff = poly2.term.coeff;
                poly2 = poly2.next;
            }
            new_Node.next = new Node(0,0,null);
            new_Node = new_Node.next;
        }



            //Returns the new polynomial
            return head;
        
        
    }
```

If I feed the two linkedLists of

```
4x^5 - 2x^3 + 2x + 3

8x^4 + 4x^3 - 3x + 9
```

This returns me the sum of

```
 0.0 + -1.0x + 2.0x^3 + 8.0x^4 + 4.0x^5
```

This is missing the first term of positive 12(the list is reversed)

Would anybody be able to assist me with solving this issue.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code and examine the variables.  For example, does `reverse()` return the expected `Node`?  See also: unit test

Comment: The issue seems to be whenever the final Node is ready to be added, the while loop breaks as the next node is null; would you have any idea of how I would rectify this?

Comment: The while loop condition calls `.next` along with calls to `.next` within the loop, which is confusing (at lest to me).  I would probably start with changing the while loop condition to `while(poly1 != null && poly2 != null)` so that `.next` is only called within the loop.

Comment: That works to an extent. However, it throws an error at the final while loop because poly1 is null for some reason. I tried to put the changing of poly1 and poly2 into an if statement to check if it is going to be set to null. This just completely crashes the program. I am kind of stumped as to what to do

Comment: @KyleHarte still need help with this